# Which HttpStatus Code should i return in my custom API?

Tags: c#, rest, api

### Scenario

I joined in a Team that is developing some API REST in Java.
As a .Net developer, i am developing the client that consumes that API, i am using RestSharp.
Sometimes i develop in the Java side, sometimes in the .Net side.
Analysing the java code, i see that when something goes wrong, like an exception or a failed bussiness rule, they (Java coders) return a HTTP status code 500 (error). Look this example:

```
try {
        loteIde = input.getFormDataPart("ideLote", String.class, Class.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Response.status(400).entity(errorHandler.getJsonError(ErrorMsgs.ERRO_INTERNO)).build();
    }
```

In the above example, if the client (API caller) dont pass the parameter "ideLote" to the request, they return a 400 error.

Or else, when some bussiness entity is missing, they return the 404 HTTP error (NotFound). Look:

```
Lote lote = loteDAO.findById(loteIde);
if (lote == null) {
    return Response.status(404).entity(errorHandler.getJsonError(ErrorMsgs.NAO_POSSIVEL_IDENTIFICAR_LOTE)).build();
}
```

They can't find the entity (Lote) so they are returning me a 400 HTTP status error.

*In my conception*, the HTTP status represent the status of the HTTP request and not the status of some bussiness rule, so, in both cases they should return me a 200 HTTP status code (nothing wrong happened with the Http Request), and some other information (maybe a XML, or JSON) about what happened in the bussiness rule, for example, they could return me something like this:

```
{
    "IdCertificado": null,
    "Errors": [
    {
       "Codigo": "0001",
       "Mensagem": "You should inform the ideLote property"
    }],
    "TemErro": true
}
```

### Question

Is my concept wrong? what should be the **default behavior** of a web API?

PS1: [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329229/should-i-return-an-http-400-bad-request-status-if-a-parameter-is-syntactically/343637#343637) answer agreed with my conception and use apocalypse and pigeons to explain it :).

PS2: More references are welcome.

Comment: do you mean 404 error? Is that a typo in your explanation? In the first snippet they return a 400 then in the next snippet its 404.

Comment: 400 is for a bad request. 404 is not found. Here is a list of Status Codes: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html. Yes, you should return a status code and a description. See the chapter on REST Status Codes here: https://books.google.de/books?id=XUaErakHsoAC&lpg=PP1&dq=restful+web+services&pg=PA197&hl=de#v=onepage&q=status%20code%20400&f=false

Comment: 4xx errors are specifically designed to tell the client something is wrong with his request so if you're doing rest (as opposed to soap for instance) you should use them let him know.

Comment: Ultimately this is all opinion based anyway, especially if it's an internal project you are free to define your rules in any way you like.

Comment: @vc74 I know my status codes, it was just, in his explanation I think he meant 404 instead of 400 when describing the 2nd snippet.

Comment: @CallumLinington Sorry, I misread your comment

Comment: Here was a good [discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329229/should-i-return-an-http-400-bad-request-status-if-a-parameter-is-syntactically/329233#329233) on 4xx status codes i participated in

Comment: It shouldnt matter which way you define your rules so long as any backend errors are correctly logged. Last thing you want to see while debugging is a 200 response when there is a fundamental issue in your backend logic. Just make sure it would make sense to the engineer who will have to debug it.

Comment: @CallumLinington isnt a type, this is the actual code. When exception occurs, 400, when something cant be found in the database 404. And yes, i also think its strange.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are correct, i will edit. Thanks, Sorry CallumLinington, i misundestood your previuous comment.

Answer (score -2):

You Need to write try catch if and in try block you need to check if fulfill condition  return data with json format else not found status code 
if data null then return exception 
i think you can easily under stand give code

```
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetNote(string ExamId, string QuestionId)
        {

            try
            {
                decimal exid = Convert.ToDecimal(ExamId);
                decimal qid = Convert.ToDecimal(QuestionId);

                var temp = new MemberQuestionsRepository().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MemberExamId == exid && x.QuestionId == qid);
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    var note = temp.Note;
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, note);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Note Found");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code looks good but keeps the concept used in the Java code example i posted, also, it does not answer if this is the "default way of develop it"